# Why does using this object in a fucntion causes Javascript TypeError (undefined) to raise?

Tags: javascript, object

I declared a new object as it follows:

```
function node(){
                this.tag        = null;
                this.Tdata      = [];
                this.Tchilds    = [];
}
```

I want to use this object in a function:

```
function Check(root /*I want to use root as type node*/) {
        for(var i = 0; i < root.Tdata.length; i++){
                if(root.Tdata[i] == -1)
                       arg++;
        }
}
```

The browser says: `TypeError: root.Tdata is undefined`

When i declare a variable (out of the function's scope) `var root = new node();` & i use `root.Tdata[]` everything works fine.

So how can i use this object in the function ?

**EDIT:**

 At the function call i did :

```
var rootExt = new node();
    rootExt.Tdata[0] = -1;
    rootExt.Tchilds[0] = -1;

    Check(rootExt);
```

Comment: How are you calling the `Check` function? I've tested your code like so: `Check(new node());` and it works as expected.

Comment: you should read the docs about new operator ..[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: You should pass the object to the function, if I understood your problem correctly.Call  `Check(new node());`

Comment: the check function is called from a loop: `var ExtRoot = new node();` and then `Check(ExtRoot);` @maddockst

Comment: @afr0ck Can you show us this code please? When I do `Check(new node());`, it works as expected.

Comment: @maddockst Do you mean declaring the function as `Check(new node());` or passing the argument as `new node();` at the function call ?

Comment: @afr0ck passing the argument as `new node()`

Comment: @maddockst It worked. But i need to declare a variable first of type `node();` , do some work on it & then passing it as an argument at the function call!

Comment: @afr0ck There's no reason that shouldn't work. Here I create a new node, add an item to `Tdata` and then call `Check`. All works as expected:  `var n = new node(); n.Tdata.push(-1); Check(n);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135533/discussion-between-maddockst-and-afr0ck).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate a `Node` object using the `new` operator, then pass that instantiated object into the invocation of the `check` function:

```
function Node() {
  this.tag = null;
  this.Tdata = [];
  this.Tchilds = [];
}

function check(root) {
  for(var i = 0; i < root.Tdata.length; i++) {
    if(root.Tdata[i] == -1) {
      arg++;
    }
  }
}

var rootNode = new Node() //instantiate a new Node
check(rootNode) //invoke check function with rootNode as argument
```

Comment: where is arg++ coming from?

Comment: unknown - its referenced in original code; however, don't think its relevant to the question at hand

Answer (score -2):

You can do this :

```
var root = {
    tag: null,
    Tdata: [],
    TChild: []
}



function Check() {
        for(var i = 0; i < root.Tdata.length; i++){
                if(root.Tdata[i] == -1)
                       arg++;
        } 
   }
```

Comment: But i need to declare other variables of type node !